# URL variable shown on page

Tags: php, url, variables

I am trying my best to describe this. I'd basically like to be able to have something like this in a url:
    mydomain.com/?&name=Courtney 
The name variable being Courtney. I would like to print it onto the page so when visited with the name=Courtney it'd state "Hello Courtney!" or "Hello Taylor!" Depending on who it is, if neither, don't display their name and just say "Hello!" I'm hoping someone here knows how to use a name in a url variable and is welling to share.

Simple in essence, but, I'm not sure how simple it is in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
```

if you want to check if the variable is available:

```
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
} else {
    echo 'Hello!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    echo "Hello ".$_GET['name']."!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($_GET['name']){
        echo "Hello " . $_GET['name'] . "!";
    }else{
        echo "Hello!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all in one line with a [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
// Collect name if present //
$name = (isset($_GET['name'])) ? ' ' . ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'])) : '';

// Echo output //
echo "Hello{$name}!";

// Output if name present //
Hello Courtney!

// Output if no name present //
Hello!
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll provide a quick example. Complicated subject, simple code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo 'Hello ' . $name;
}
else{
echo 'No name supplied'
}
?>
```

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why you are downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use the current page url then after page load you can use

```
var address= document.URL
```

then extract the name (as url in your question is like 'mydomain.com/?&name=Courtney')

```
var name= address.substring(address.lastIndexOf('=') + 1)

if(name.length>0)
 {alert("Hello "+name)}
else
alert("Hello")
```